# Unexpected value for reduce function

Tags: javascript

In the following reduce function, if I create and initialize a variable sum to the parameter acc, it successfully returns the accumulated value of 8 for the array [4,1,3]. However, if I use the acc parameter variable inside the function it returns 21. Why is that? Why does acc sum to 21?

// The array and add function provided to the reduce function

```
const nums = [4, 1, 3];
const add = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

// Returns 8

```
function reduce(nums, func, acc) {
  let sum = acc;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += func(acc, nums[i]);
  }

  return sum;
}
```

// Returns 21

```
function reduce(nums, func, acc) {

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    acc += func(acc, nums[i]);
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Comment: How do you use the `add()` and `reduce()` functions? JavaScript [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method provides a simple(r) way to reduce an array to a single value. It does the iteration for you, all you have to do is to provide a function that combines an item with a partial result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reduce functions are defined incorrectly. In each iteration, accumulator should be set to return value of `func`, not increased by it. This line:

```
acc += func(acc, nums[i]);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
acc = func(acc, nums[i]);
```

Your first reduce function works correctly because you are always passing **initial** accomulator value, i.e. `0`, to `func`.